# ranking transactions trend for each customer per year

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

working on jupyter, my dataframe have number of transaction per customer per year and field that indicates the "trend - up for more transactions than last year, down for less transaction than last year, null for the first year.

I want to create a numerator that for every "up" per customer will raised by 1 and for every "down" will "reduced" by 1.

I understand that I need first to sort the df and than to build a loop that will run on the number of customers and an inside loop that will run for every year but I need help.

DF SAMPLE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group number': [1,1,1,1,3,3,3],
    'year': ['2012','2013','2014','2015','2011','2012','2013'],
    'trend': [NaN,'down','up','up',NaN,'down','up']
})
```

this is what I did so far:

```
df =pd.read_excel('totals_new.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1').sort_values(['group number', 'year'])

noofgroups = len(df['group number'].unique())
yearspergroup = df.groupby('group number')['year'].nunique()

vtrend =0

for i in noofgroups:
    for j in yearspergroup:
        if df["trend"] == "up":
            vtrend = vtrend+1
        if df["trend"] == "down":
            vtrend = vtrend-1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is a better fit for this community if you can provide a code snippet of what you have tried already, so we can suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use nested `np.where()` to convert your `trend` column and then perform a `groupby()` and `agg()`. Take this sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group number': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2],
    'year': ['2017','2016','2018','2017','2016','2018','2017','2016','2018','2017','2016','2018',
        '2017','2016','2018','2017','2016','2018','2017','2016','2018','2017'],
    'trend': ['up','down','up',np.nan,'up','down',np.nan,'up','up','up','down',
        'up',np.nan,'up','up','up','down','up','up','up',np.nan,'down']
    })
```

Yields:

```
    group number  year trend
0              1  2017    up
1              1  2016  down
2              1  2018    up
3              1  2017   NaN
4              1  2016    up
5              1  2018  down
6              1  2017   NaN
7              2  2016    up
8              2  2018    up
9              2  2017    up
10             2  2016  down
11             2  2018    up
12             2  2017   NaN
13             1  2016    up
14             1  2018    up
15             1  2017    up
16             2  2016  down
17             2  2018    up
18             1  2017    up
19             2  2016    up
20             1  2018   NaN
21             2  2017  down
```

Then:

```
df['trend'] = np.where(df['trend']=='up', 1, np.where(df['trend']=='down', -1, 0))

df.groupby(['group number','year']).agg({'trend': 'sum'})
```

Returns:

```
                   trend
group number year       
1            2016      1
             2017      3
             2018      1
2            2016      0
             2017      0
             2018      3
```

Comment: thanks, but for the first year for every group the trend is "null" so the where clause need to take null as zero, can you fix it ?

Comment: You need to post a sample of your dataframe, for this very reason.

Comment: Do not post as an image, include it as formatted text in your original post. Please see the posting guidelines

Comment: thanks, i've tried but its automatically posting as image :(

Comment: added to the post hope it's ok

Comment: thanks rahlf23  but the numbers don't accumulate, i need them to accumulate for every group number.

Answer (score 0):

This case is probably closed by now but, here's a possible solution since it did not come to a conclusion previously.

```
import pandas as pd

"""
In this case, the original dataframe is already properly sorted by group number and year.
If it isn't, the 2 columns should be sorted first
"""
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group number': [1,1,1,1,3,3,3],
    'year': ['2012','2013','2014','2015','2011','2012','2013'],
    'trend': [np.nan,'down','up','up', np.nan,'down','up']
}) 

df['trend_val'] = df.loc[df['trend'].isna() == False, 'trend'].map(lambda x: -1 if x == 'down' else 1)
df.join(df.groupby('group number')['trend_val'].cumsum(), rsuffix='_cumulative')

>>>df
   group number  year trend  trend_val  trend_val_cumulative
0             1  2012   NaN        NaN                   NaN
1             1  2013  down       -1.0                  -1.0
2             1  2014    up        1.0                   0.0
3             1  2015    up        1.0                   1.0
4             3  2011   NaN        NaN                   NaN
5             3  2012  down       -1.0                  -1.0
6             3  2013    up        1.0                   0.0
```